# What does "le barchette di carta" mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idioms, word-meaning, translation

Is there a specific idiomatic meaning for "barchette di carta" (in English). I'm trying to translate the following sentence but it refuses to make sense.

> "Montale 'fanciullo invecchiato' vede dalla lontananza o in una specie di ravvicinato ormai incomprensibile le barchette di carta, è nella 'fine dell'infanzia'."

I have

> "Montale, 'aged child' seen from the distance or in a kind of already incomprehensible reconciliation (of?) the paper boats, is in the 'end of childhood'."

Comment: Christina, welcome to Italian.SE. You shouldn't be asking for translations into English, especially idiomatic ones: we are mostly Italian speaking here. You are welcome to ask for explanation of Italian words and phrases, while English.SE or ELL.SE are better choices to ask for English phrases to express a given idea.

Comment: _Montale, "aged child", sees the paper boats from afar or in a sort of already incomprehensible close-up – he is in the "end of childhood"._

Comment: Allora scusa, ero confusa sul sito. Grazie Mauro, molto simile a quel che avevo pensato ma pensavo che fosse sbagliato... e mettevo "reconciliation" invece di "close-up": dubitavo! L'italiano manca.

Comment: Figurati, il ravvicinato di cui parla questo testo va inteso in senso fotografico, ma è comunque incomprensibile quanto la visione da lontano. Sta dicendo insomma che Montale parla delle «navicelle» di carta con una forma di distacco, non è immerso nella sua infanzia ma si identifica semmai col «galantuomo» che passa.

Comment: La sfida della traduzione qui è, come al solito, -ette. Non c'è mai un vero modo di tradurre le sfumature dei nostri diminutivi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it refers to the 'small paper boats' that he used to make and play with as a child.   I think they are used as a sort of symbol of his childhood to which he makes a specific reference in the sentence ("è nella fine dell'infanzia").

[image: barchetta di carta']

Answer (score 3):

As Josh61 explains, the “barchette di carta” are just small toy boats made of paper (especially out of newspapers). Maybe you are just baffled by the sentence structure. Read it as «Montale ‘fanciullo invecchiato’ vede le barchette di carta dalla lontananza o in una specie di ravvicinato [= da un punto di vista solo apparentemente vicino] ormai incomprensibile; è nella ‘fine dell'infanzia’».